# validating json file using java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am using classes which came from [json.org](http://json.org/java/). Using them, can someone suggest a sniplet of the code which would let one parse the input stream to see whether it represents a valid json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the JSONObject [constructor](http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) and it throws JSONException if the source string is not proper JSON formatted String.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. Such an obvious thing .. completely escaped me